# Is there a postgres fuzzy match faster than pg_trgm?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, fuzzy-search

I have a Postgres table with about 5 million records and I want to find the closest match to an input key. I tried using trigrams with the pg_trgm module, but it took roughly 5 seconds per query, which is too slow for my needs.

Is there a faster way to do fuzzy match within Postgres?

Comment: How are the keys structured? alpha-numeric? int only?

Comment: The index is built on an attribute of type text.

Comment: Please show us the output of "explain analyze" of your query.

Comment: explain analyze select * from fbsimple where lower(en) % 'france';
QUERY PLAN                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on fbsimple  (cost=399.17..20762.45 rows=5600 width=898) (actual time=2965.130..8722.165 rows=20 loops=1)
   Filter: (lower(en) % 'france'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on lower_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..397.77 rows=5600 width=0) (actual time=2404.114..2404.114 rows=43677 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (lower(en) % 'france'::text)
 Total runtime: 8741.179 ms
(5 rows)

Comment: The index referred to in the above plan is:
CREATE INDEX lower_trgm_idx ON fbsimple USING gin (lower(en) gin_trgm_ops);

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the estimations of result size in your explain output are way off. This is not unexpected as it is very hard to estimate results of full text search well.

This causes Postgresql to use bad query plan. Try to disable bitmap scan (set enable_bitmapscan=off) and try again.

Answer (score 1):

[Soundex](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) is an alternative fuzzy match, but it can be *very* fuzzy. I would stick with the trigram matching, if you can. Is there another criterion you could use to make the trigram search work on a smaller set of results?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are looking for, Postgres can also do matches on regular expressions, instead of the standard "like" syntax.   It may be a better fit for you.